# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1 in ServerSideStateHelper

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss

When I try to load a widget via primefaces running on jboss 8, I see the below error. jsf imple jar used is : jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1

Can someone help me understand what could cause this exception?

```
2015-08-06 02:34:30,712 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-18) java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1955)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.getState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:313)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.isStateless(ServerSideStateHelper.java:515)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.isStateless(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:168)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:544)
```